# How to approach ((P → Q) → P) → P?

Tags: logic

!!! For full disclosure, this question was assigned in my university class. !!!

I'm having a terrible time trying to prove without premises ((P → Q) → P) → P.
I've attempted approaching it multiple different ways:

1) I've tried starting a subproof assuming NOT ((P → Q) → P) → P, and then I was going to use proof by cases to introduce a contradiction, finally asserting NOT NOT ... and then eliminating the NOTs.

2) I've also tried starting a subproof of (P → Q) → P and using subproofs to prove by cases that it is true in every case.

3) I've tried starting with P->Q <-> ~P v Q as well.

Every time I attempt to solve this, I'm puzzled with what seems like an issue where I don't know how to prove (P → Q) to start, or how to justify by cases that if that is the case P must also be true.

I end up proving something other than the intended conclusion, and don't know how I got there...

Any advice or examples that could illustrate how to attempt this or get me started would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With *Natural Deduction* :

1) $(P \to Q) \to P$ --- assumed [a]

2) $\lnot P$ --- assumed [b]

3) $P$ --- assumed [c]

4) $\bot$ --- from 2) and 3)

5) $Q$ --- from 4) by $\bot$-rule

6) $P \to Q$ --- from 3) and 5) by $\to$-intro, discharging [c]

7) $P$ --- from 1) and 6) by $\to$-elim

8) $\bot$ --- from 2) and 7)

9) $P$ --- from 2) and 8) by *Double Negation*, discharging [b]

> 10) $((P \to Q) \to P) \to P$ --- from 1) and 9) by $\to$-intro, discharging [a].

Comment: This is a correct, concise answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what proof formalism you have available, I can’t do more than outline an argument, but it’s one that you should be able to formalize. Assume the negation of the statement; then you can infer $(P\to Q)\to P$ and $\neg P$. These in turn imply $\neg(P\to Q)$, which implies $P$, giving you the desired contradiction.

Comment: I've attempted to follow your logic, and it made a lot of sense. Ultimately, however, the proof started becoming incredibly messy and I found myself with Analytic Consequence assertions that still need proved. Thanks!

Comment: @Anon: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Your third strategy seems good. $$((P \to Q)\to P) \to P \equiv ¬(¬(¬P\vee Q)\vee P) \vee P \equiv ((¬P \vee Q)\wedge ¬P)\vee P \\ \equiv ¬P \vee (¬P \wedge Q) \vee P$$ is true.